# Unknown persistence entity error

Tags: neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I am currently using SDN 3.0.1 in production but I would like to benefit from last improvement from SDN 3.3.0 (cf: http://jexp.de/blog/2014/12/spring-data-neo4j-improving-remoting-performance/). For this I had to migrate my grails project (which is using Spring 3) to the latest grails version (which is using spring boot and Spring 4).

But it's not working as expected.. I am getting this error when trying to fetch data from Neo4J 2.1.8 server:

```
Unknown persistent entity com.motards.nous.server.v1.dao.repository.relationship.domain.Ride. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.8.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Unknown persistent entity com.motards.nous.server.v1.dao.repository.relationship.domain.Ride
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IterableWrapper$MyIteratorWrapper.underlyingObjectToObject(IterableWrapper.java:57) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.next(IteratorWrapper.java:47) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.addToCollection(IteratorUtil.java:382) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.addToCollection(IteratorUtil.java:461) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
    at com.motards.nous.server.v1.RideService.$tt__getAllPublicRides(RideService.groovy:54) ~[main/:na]
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93) ~[grails-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:90) ~[grails-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at com.motards.nous.server.v1.PublicRideController.index(PublicRideController.groovy:29) ~[main/:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

Here is my Neo4J configuration:

```
@Configuration
    @EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.motards.nous.server.v1.dao", repositoryImplementationPostfix = "Repository")
    static class MyNeo4jConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration {

        MyNeo4jConfiguration() {
            setBasePackage("com.motards.nous.server.v1.dao")
        }

        @Bean
        GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
            return new SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase("http://neo4j:7474/db/data")
        }

        @Bean
        Neo4jMappingContext neo4jMappingContext() {
            return new Neo4jMappingContext()
        }

    }
```

Did I miss something ?

-- EDIT --

Here my updated configuration after separate the entities from repositories.

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.nousmotards.core.repositories.neo4j", repositoryImplementationPostfix = "Repository")
class MyNeo4jConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    @Resource
    Environment environment

    MyNeo4jConfiguration() {
        setBasePackage("com.nousmotards.core.domains.neo4j")
    }

    @Bean
    GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase("http://${environment.getProperty("nm.neo4j.host")}:${environment.getProperty("nm.neo4j.port")}/db/data")
    }

}
```

Here the complete stacktrace that I get: 
https://gist.github.com/evoxmusic/615ac940186ec97d2e89

-- EDIT 2 --

When I add

```
@Bean
    Neo4jMappingContext neo4jMappingContext() {
        return new Neo4jMappingContext()
    }
```

the application start correctly, but when I try to query neo4j entity I get this error:

```
2015-06-25 15:54:31.418 ERROR 42902 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Unknown persistent entity com.nousmotards.core.domains.neo4j.MyRootNode] with root cause

org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Unknown persistent entity com.nousmotards.core.domains.neo4j.MyRootNode
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:177)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.cacheType(Neo4jMappingContext.java:173)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.isNodeEntity(Neo4jMappingContext.java:167)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.isNodeEntity(Neo4jTemplate.java:340)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.conversion.EntityResultConverter.doConvert(EntityResultConverter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.DefaultConverter.convert(DefaultConverter.java:44)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.conversion.EntityResultConverter.convert(EntityResultConverter.java:165)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.QueryResultBuilder$1.underlyingObjectToObject(QueryResultBuilder.java:86)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IterableWrapper$MyIteratorWrapper.underlyingObjectToObject(IterableWrapper.java:57)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.next(IteratorWrapper.java:47)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.single(IteratorUtil.java:335)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.singleOrNull(IteratorUtil.java:128)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.singleOrNull(IteratorUtil.java:286)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.QueryResultBuilder.singleOrNull(QueryResultBuilder.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.dispatchQuery(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery$1.doWithGraph(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.doExecute(Neo4jTemplate.java:465)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.access$000(Neo4jTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate$2.doInTransaction(Neo4jTemplate.java:479)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.exec(Neo4jTemplate.java:476)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.execute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:371)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.findNodeByUUID(Unknown Source)
    at com.nousmotards.core.repositories.neo4j.MyRootNodeRepository$findNodeByUUID.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.nousmotards.core.services.MyService$_doCacheWithRedisByUUID_closure11.doCall(MyService.groovy:233)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.nousmotards.core.services.RedisService.withRedis(RedisService.groovy:21)
    at com.nousmotards.core.services.RedisService$withRedis.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.nousmotards.core.services.MyService.doCacheWithRedisByUUID(MyService.groovy:230)
    at com.nousmotards.core.services.RiderService.doCacheWithRedisByUUID(RiderService.groovy)
    at com.nousmotards.core.services.MyService$doCacheWithRedisByUUID.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.nousmotards.core.services.MyService.getFromRedisByUUID(MyService.groovy:273)
    at com.nousmotards.core.services.RiderService.getFromRedisByUUID(RiderService.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1206)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1120)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1151)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1120)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.nousmotards.core.services.MyService$_closure2.doCall(MyService.groovy:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1206)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1120)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at com.nousmotards.core.services.MyService$_closure2.call(MyService.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureStaticMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureStaticMetaMethod.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:88)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.nousmotards.core.services.RiderService.get(RiderService.groovy:40)
    at com.nousmotards.core.services.RiderService$get.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.nousmotards.core.controllers.TestController.show(TestController.groovy:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:295)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Here is my "MyRootNode" entity

```
@NodeEntity
abstract class MyRootNode implements RestPowered, Cacheable, NotificationObservable {

    // internal id for Neo4J
    @GraphId
    Long id

    // exposed API id
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    Long uuid = Math.abs(UUID.randomUUID().getMostSignificantBits())

    @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.SIMPLE, indexName = MyIndexNames.NODE_CREATED_DATE)
    Date createdDate = new Date()

    @Fetch
    @RelatedToVia(type = MyRelationshipTypes.IS_NOTIFICATION_OBSERVER, direction = Direction.INCOMING)
    Set<IsNotificationObserver> notificationObservers

    @Transient
    Class<?> doLoadClass(final String name) {
        this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(name)
    }

    @Transient
    String getType() {
        getClass().name.split("\\.")[-1]
    }

    @Transient
    Map getShortPropertiesMap() {
        if (id) {
            final MyRootNode rootNode = this.class.getRedis(id)

            return [
                    type           : type,
                    id             : rootNode.uuid,
                    id_str         : rootNode.uuid.toString(),
                    displayed_name : rootNode.displayedName,
                    displayed_photo: rootNode.displayedPhoto
            ]
        }

        return [
                type           : type,
                id             : uuid,
                id_str         : uuid.toString(),
                displayed_name : displayedName,
                displayed_photo: displayedPhoto
        ]
    }

    @Override
    Map<Object, Object> getPropertiesMap() {
        if (id) {
            final MyRootNode rootNode = this.class.getRedis(id)

            return [
                    type           : type,
                    id             : rootNode.uuid,
                    id_str         : rootNode.uuid.toString(),
                    created_date   : rootNode.createdDate,
                    displayed_name : rootNode.displayedName,
                    displayed_photo: rootNode.displayedPhoto
            ]
        }

        return [
                type           : type,
                id             : uuid,
                id_str         : uuid.toString(),
                created_date   : createdDate,
                displayed_name : displayedName,
                displayed_photo: displayedPhoto
        ]
    }

    @Override
    void setPropertiesMap(final Map map) {
        this.propertiesMap = map
    }

    @Transient
    Map<Object, Object> getPublicPropertiesMap() {
        [
                type           : type,
                id             : uuid,
                id_str         : uuid.toString(),
                created_date   : createdDate,
                displayed_name : displayedName,
                displayed_photo: displayedPhoto
        ]
    }

    @Transient
    Map<Object, Object> getElasticsearchPropertiesMap() {
        propertiesMap
    }

    @Override
    Map<Object, Object> getCacheablePropertiesMap() {
        [
                type                 : getClass().name,
                id                   : id,
                uuid                 : uuid,
                createdDate          : createdDate.time,
                notificationObservers: notificationObservers.collect { it.id }
        ]
    }

    @Override
    Object buildFromCacheableJsonString(String jsonString) {
        final def j = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonString)
        id = j.id as Long
        uuid = j.uuid as Long
        createdDate = new Date(j.createdDate as Long)
        notificationObservers = j.notificationObservers.collect {
            // a bit dirty but made its job !
            try {
                IsNotificationObserver?.getRedis(it)
            } catch (Exception e) {
                null
            }
        } - null

        return this
    }

}
```

Comment: Is that the right package for your domain entities? `"com.motards.nous.server.v1.dao"`

Comment: Hi @MichaelHunger, yes it is. I have change this to separate repositories and entities but it does not work as well... I am using spring data redis, mongodb, elasticsearch and neo4j in the same project now.. I'll update the post cause I have change the things to make it compliant to the documentation.

Comment: I have edited my post, I hope you will find what is wrong.

Comment: Is @Transient working properly with SDN 3.3.0 ?

Comment: I made some tests and it seems that the SDN does not like generic like "Map"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem.. weird Spring Data Neo4J...
I had to change all "Map" object to something concrete like "HashMap" and it works now.

Seems to be a bug...